# FFmpeg: Change the timing/easing of an XFade transition in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Given an xfade transition filter such as this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=slideleft:duration=1:offset=4,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

Is it possible to alter the timing/easing of the xfade transition? For instance, the above slideleft transition seems to be linear in the output video. How could one achieve a non-linear easing such as a [cubic ease in](https://easings.net/#easeInCubic) for the transition between the two clips?

Comment: idk how to slideleft, but wipeleft with easing will be something like that: `transition=custom:expr='if(gt(P, (X/W)*(X/W)*(X/W)),A,B)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xfade custom transition, slideleft with easing

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 1.1 -i in1.png \
-loop 1 -t 1.1 -i in2.png \
-filter_complex "
[0]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];
[1]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];
[v0][v1]xfade=duration=1:offset=0.1:transition=custom:
expr='
if(lt(X+W*pow(1-P,3),W),
 if(eq(PLANE,0),a0(X+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,1),a1(X+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,2),a2(X+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,3),a3(X+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
,if(eq(PLANE,0),b0(X-W+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,1),b1(X-W+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,2),b2(X-W+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
+if(eq(PLANE,3),b3(X-W+W*pow(1-P,3),Y),0)
)'
" -y /tmp/output.mp4
ffplay -loop 0 /tmp/output.mp4
```